# Is it okay to apply for a closed job?

Tags: job-search, applications, linkedin

I was about to apply to a full-time job through LinkedIn. I just found the job and was working on my resume and cover letters but unfortunately, it was already closed when I finished (which is unusual since I remember it said it's been posted only for 3 days when I found it). However, the company still has the job open on another portal but this one is only on contract*.

I'm still looking for the full-time though, so my question is: Is there any possible way(s) that I could still apply to the full-time opportunity and if there is, what's the best way to do this? And also, would this look okay to the hiring managers?

*They actually stated that they're looking for full-time positions OR months contract for the position on LinkedIn.

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: What do you mean by okay? It seems doubtful to me that you will be selected for a position they are no longer seeking. Your application is likely to be ignored.

Comment: I mean if it would be appropriate at all if I apply since I found many articles that tell it's okay to apply for a job after the deadline. But my case is a bit different, there was no stated deadline, it was just closed. And I couldn't post my application unless I reach the recruiter or some other ways

Answer (score 8):

> Is there any possible way(s) that I could still apply to the full-time
>   opportunity and if there is, what's the best way to do this?

Certainly.

Just apply as you would for any other job.

At worst you'll be told that the job is closed. At best you'll get the full-time job. Somewhere in the middle you'll be told that it's now a contract position and asked if you want to apply for that.

> And also, would this look okay to the hiring managers?

It should look just fine.

Comment: thanks Joe. I actually thought to reach the recruiter personally or send my application to the company e-mail, but I'm not sure if I should tell them that I missed and if it would look unprofessional (knowing the job is closed)

Answer (score 1):

It's no problem applying after the official closing date. And you apply just as you would have applied before the official closing date. Of course applying three months later will be a bit pointless, but a few days late is no problem.

Look at it from the point of view of the employer: They want a good employee. They don't want to interview forever but make a decision soonish. So the plan is to get applications until date X, interview people until X plus some days, make a decision shortly afterwards, then hire the best person (or the second best if the best one started elsewhere).

They are going to get some applications late. If they didn't get many applications, they'll be happy about yours, late or not. As long as they can fit you in for an interview, or if your application looks really good, you should be fine. If they got tons of applications, yours won't have a chance, but chances where low anyway.

Worst possible case is that they ignore your application. Nothing much lost. And nobody will hold it against you.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any possible way(s) that I could still apply to the full-time opportunity and if there is, what's the best way to do this?

If the application is closed, as you mention, then there is little you can do to revert that situation so you can apply for it. Applying to the post will most likely result in you not getting a response (but, if you already drafted your application, why not send it anyways?)

The best chance you got is to keep your options open and continue job-hunting and interviewing for other jobs that are of your interest.

Also, if this one was really interesting to you, consider keeping an eye on the company in case they open future opportunities, so you can apply timely next time. Additionally, consider browsing other jobs offered by that company in case there is one there that will also be of interest to you.